# Can't create subscription in Sybase Replication server

Tags: replication, sybase, hana

We have primary source database as Oracle 11gR2 and target as SAP HANA. We are trying to test SAP - Sybase Replication server for replication from Primary ORACLE to Target HANA. We are facing issue while creating subscription:

- Command:

  ```
  create subscription ptab1_sub for ptab1_repdef with replicate at HDV00.SRSUSER
  without holdlock direct_load user RA_MAINT password sybase
  ```
- `RA_MAINT`/sybase is our primary database maintenance user and has Read/Write access on source table.
- Table we are trying to replicate is in `RA_USER` schema.
- `SRSUSER` is target schema in HANA database

Issue we are facing is that the maintenance user for the primary database cannot create subscriptions using atomic, non-atomic or incremental methods.

Need help to resolve this issue.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the primary user instead of the maint user?

Comment: tried with that getting - getting error -Can not connect into primary database pds.pdb with user
name(RA_USER) and password(********).

Comment: You'll need to dig deeper and find out *why* you cannot connect. Incorrect username/password for example?